# Button click calls panel method without arguments

Tags: java, swing, java-8

I have JFrame and inside that I have JPanel and inside of that I have one button. And when I click I want it call some method with I specify. Is that somehow possible without parameters?

This is how I have done it until now:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
JPanel container = new JPanel();
frame.add(container);

JButton button = new JButton("Button");
button.addActionListener( e -> mySpecialMethod());  // I have to create action performed method with has ActionEvent as parameter.
```

...

Is there a simpler way? It seems redundant to do it all the time. Something like `button.addActionListener(Foo::bar);` and `public void bar(){....}`

Comment: Seriously? `this::mySpecialMethod` has *more* characters than `e->mySpecialMethod()`. And what’s wrong with an expression which makes it visible that you are effectively dropping (not using) the event argument?

Answer (score 1):

You can use method reference here only if your method has an `ActionEvent` parameter:

```
button.addActionListener( this::mySpecialMethod );

void mySpecialMethod( ActionEvent e ) { ... }
```

If your method has no parameter, then interface signature and method signature don't match, so you will have a compilation error. Probably that's a matter of taste, but for me `e -> mySpecialMethod()` looks not very redundant (especially compared to anonymous classes I had to use prior to Java 8).

Comment: You could use `EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, this, "mySpecialMethod")` before Java 8, which had its own downsides, but was more compact than an anonymous inner class.